# Compound paths invisible while imported in Blender

Tags: modeling, export, import, svg

[image: file]

I'm doing a logotype for a friend and I wanted to print it in 3D but unfortunately my svg (created in illustrator) doesn't show some of my compound paths in Blender and I can't figure why.

[image: Blender file]

Comment: Can you upload the SVG file?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with compound path, try to remove compound path, and make the hole/space real path